# Как в Android получить видео с конкретного устройства (/dev/video*)?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, kernel, android-camera

Всем привет!

Есть устройство на Android, к которому подключена камера на [EM28XX](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Em28xx_devices). Для поддержки этой камеры были собраны модули для ядра: tveeprom.ko, em28xx.ko, em28xx-v4l.ko и em28xx-alsa.ko.

Подключаю данные модули с помощью insmod (кроме alsa). Через ADB вижу вот такую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно такой же репорт выдает и Ubuntu, и Debian, в которых поддержка em28xx реализована по умолчанию. И в этих ОС самым главным являлось правильное указание параметра card.

Но теперь возникает вопрос: а как получить видео-поток с этого устройства? В Ubuntu и Debian можно использовать xawtv или mplayer с указанием конкретного устройства (в данном случае /dev/video3). А как то же самое проделать в Android?

В принципе подойдет как готовое решение в виде какого-нибудь приложения, так и хоть какой-нибудь мануал для Andoid Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы сделали порт HAL драйвера cameralib [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342902/android-kernel-drivers-for-camera-device?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), тогда если все правильно и камера заработала нужно использовать Android Camera API [доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) или стандартное приложение Камера для просмотра